# python как читать текст из файла по тире

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, txt

как с помощью python прочитать текст который разделен тире например у меня есть txt файл в нем написаная такая информация:
--time рандомная цифра
как сделать чтобы программа открыла файл и написала рандомную цифру которая в файле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:

    s = re.findall('--time \d+', file.read())
    for i in s:
        print(i.split()[1])
```

test.txt

```
 rr --time 423423  fsd
hf --time 423865423 fsdfs
vb --time 423424523 dfsdf
--time 654
--time 345  dfsdfs
--time 42534
```

вывод:

```
423423
423865423
423424523
654
345
42534
```